Majorizarion expression of maximum
If $ x\in\mathbb{R}^n $, we note $x_{[1]}\geq\cdots\geq x_{[n]}$ the permutation that arranges $x$ in a nonincreasing order. For vectors $ x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n $, we note $ x \prec y $ if $\sum_{i=1}^k x_{[i]} \leq \sum_{i=1}^k y_{[i]},  k = 1, \ldots, n-1$
with equality when $ k = n$.
It is easy to prove that if $q\in\left(\frac{1}{n},1\right)$, $ p\in\mathbb{R}^n $ such that $p_i\geq0$ for all $i$, $\sum_{i=1}^np_i=1$, then $p_{[1]}\geq q$ if and only if $(q,\frac{1-q}{n-1},\cdots,\frac{1-q}{n-1})\prec p$?
My question is: is there any similar result in the more general case $\sum_{i=1}^np_i\leq1$? The result can hold on a restricted set of $p$ and $q$.

Now I finally understand the motivation behind your original question. More precisely, with the additional context you gave here it is now clear that your previous condition $1-S\geq\frac{1-q}{n}$ should've instead read $q\geq\frac{S}n$:

Theorem. Let $p\in\mathbb R_+^n$ be given and define $S:=\sum_{i=1}^np_i$. Then for all $q\geq\frac{S}n$ it holds that $p_{[1]}\geq q$ if and only if $(q,\frac{S-q}{n-1},\ldots,\frac{S-q}{n-1})\prec p$.

Proof. As you wrote in your post you already proved the case $S=1$, i.e. in that case for all $q\geq\frac{1}{n}$ it holds that
$$
p_{[1]}\geq q\ \Leftrightarrow\ \Big(q,\frac{1-q}{n-1},\cdots,\frac{1-q}{n-1}\Big)\prec p\,.\tag1
$$
Thus all we have to do is to generalize this to arbitrary $p\in\mathbb R_+^n$.
Indeed, because $S\geq 0$ by assumption (actually the case $p=0$ is trivial so we may even assume $S>0$) the following chain of equivalences holds:
\begin{align*}
p_{[1]}\geq q\quad&\Leftrightarrow\quad \Big(\frac pS\Big)_{[1]}\geq \frac qS\\
&\overset{(1)}\Leftrightarrow\quad \Big(\frac qS,\frac{1-\frac qS}{n-1},\cdots,\frac{1-\frac qS}{n-1}\Big)\prec \frac pS\\
&\overset{\cdot S}\Leftrightarrow\quad \Big(q,\frac{S-q}{n-1},\cdots,\frac{S-q}{n-1}\Big)\prec p\tag*{$\square$}
\end{align*}
In particular, the counterexample I gave worked precisely because it violated the updated assumption: $q=\frac18<\frac14=\frac{\frac14+\frac14}2=\frac Sn$ meaning $q$ was too small.
